# When are the following equivalences correct?

Tags: gate-synthesis

[image]

I can't figure out how the equivalences in the picture hold.

The picture comes from [this recent publication on PRA](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.03533.pdf).

EDIT: I think I might have been mislead by the gate represenation.
In fact, the gate is more common to express the $CZ$ gate and not a $Z\otimes Z$ gate. What's more, I'm not really used to Ising operators and I can't see why there can be found implementation (both logical and physical) for a gate which can be expressed with single-qubit gates.

Comment: In your post, could you please provide some more details on how you've attempted to answer your question? What aspects confuse you?

Comment: I checked by using the channel-state duality by using Quirk tool and I get different density matrices. I used  the $Z$ gate instead of the $R_z$, as they should be equivalent, up to global phase.

Comment: I think that I misunderstood the kind of operator they represent with the red gate. To me that's a controlled-$Z$ not a $Z\otimes Z$. What's more, I don't get the general importance of such kind of complexity for an operator which admits implementation by only using single qubit gates.

Comment: @DanieleCuomo please add any relevant detail by editing the post, not in comments

Comment: Done; hoping now my real doubts comes out!

Answer (score 3):

These are indeed correct. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.03505.pdf) as well starting at Eq. (31).

Start with the first equivalence: ZZ $\equiv$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ $R_Z^{(1)}(\theta)$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ as given, though you can compute this in terms of exponentiated Pauli operators. From your question, I'm guessing you aren't asking about that though.

To get the 2nd equivalence, we have CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ ZZ $=$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ $R_Z^{(1)}(\theta) $ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$. Notice the two CNOT gates next to each other. Those cancel each other out becoming the identity CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ = $\mathbb{1}$. So you get CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ ZZ $\equiv$ $R_Z^{(1)}(\theta) $ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$.

The 3rd equivalence is the same trick but we also cancel the $R_Z$ gate: $R_Z^{(1)}(-\theta)$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ ZZ $=$ $R_Z^{(1)}(-\theta)$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ $R_Z^{(1)}(\theta) $ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$. We reduce the CNOTs just like before: $R_Z^{(1)}(-\theta)$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ ZZ $=$ $R_Z^{(1)}(-\theta)$ $R_Z^{(1)}(\theta)$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$. Now we have two single qubit gates that also cancel each other out $R_Z^{(1)}(-\theta)$ $R_Z^{(1)}(\theta) = \mathbb{1}$. So we get $R_Z^{(1)}(-\theta)$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$ ZZ $=$ CNOT$^{(0,1)}$

Comment: Perhaps it was just a problem of nomenclature. That gate to me is the $CZ$ gate, not the gate $Z\otimes Z$.